# Can Intellij / Android Studio merge multiple catch blocks into one?

Tags: java, android-studio, inheritance, intellij-idea, exception

I have to **refactor** something like this:

```
class BarException extends FooException 

class BazException extends FooException 

try {
    // Some risky stuff
} catch (BarException e) {
    debug(e);
} catch (BazException e) {
    debug(e);
}
```

Is Intellij or Android Studio capable to rewrite the catch blocks into:

```
} catch (FooException e) {
    debug(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best IDEA can do is to automatically create

```
} catch (BarException | BazException  e) {
    debug(e);
}
```

To do that you can run the inspection "Identical 'catch' branches in 'try' statement"

(for example menu Analyze -> Run Inspection by name).

To change that into "FooException" changes semantics because it cannot be proven automatically that there are no other subclasses of FooException (after all Java can dynamically load new classes).
Of course, you yourself might know that, so the refactoring makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding set of try catches, You can do

- Highlight '`//Some risky stuff`'
- Code -> Surround With.. -> try/catch

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I initially forgot to mention I was refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

At least in IntelliJ Utimate 2018.2, after running the inspection `Identical 'catch' branches in 'try' statement` (started by "Run inspection by name"), you can click on `Collapse 'catch' blocks` button to automatically merge the catch statements